# How to list all different 2-element list in a list in haskell?

Tags: haskell

For example, I have `[1,2,3]`, I want to get `[[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]`. Besides, in the list, `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` are assumed as same so just leave one in the result, and I also want to add a condition, like 'sum of the elements in sub-list is smaller than 4', then the result should be [[1,2]].

Any one knows how to solve this?

Comment: What did you try yourself? What did not work?

Comment: I make that mistake way more than I should admit...

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension:

```
input = [1,2,3]
output = [ [x,y] | x <- input, y <- input, x < y, x + y < 4]

-- [[1,2]]
```

Comment: what if the type of input is [String], like ["hello","hi","lol"], how to select all different lists?

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Comment: @Sawyer `x+y<4` makes no sense for strings. To select **all** combinations, use the function `choose` as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function which works for different types:

```
import           Math.Combinat.Sets (choose)

select :: Int -> ([a] -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
select k filtering list = filter filtering (choose k list)
```

Examples:

```
>>> select 2 (\x -> sum x < 5) [1,2,3]
[[1,2],[1,3]]
>>> select 2 (not . elem "hello") ["hello", "how", "are", "you"]
[["how","are"],["how","you"],["are","you"]]
```